# Find all numbers that are invertible in a certain set.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

So the question goes like this:

> Determine all invertible numbers in $$ {Z}_{24}$$

I know that a invertible number in a certain set is an integer that multiplied with a certain other integer in the set is equal to 1.

But I don't know how to find all numbers!

Any hint you could give me? A small push in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) it is all the numbers coprime to $24$